# How can we configure value.subject.name.strategy for schemas in nodejs Kafka producers?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

How can we configure subject naming strategy of avro schema, I want to configure *key.subject.name.strategy* and *value.subject.name.strategy*. I know this could be done in [Java](https://karengryg.io/2018/08/18/multi-schemas-in-one-kafka-topic/) but couldn't find a way to do it in node. I have comeup with below code till now.

```
function getSchemaRegistryClient() {
        let saslUsername = ACCESS_KEY;
        let saslPassword = SECRET_KEY;
        let schemaRegistryUrl = SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL;

        var registryClient = new SchemaRegistry({
            host: `https://${saslUsername}:${saslPassword}@${schemaRegistryUrl}`
        });

    return registryClient;
}

function getKafkaClient() {
  console.log('Fetching Kafka Client');

  var kafkaClient = new Kafka({
    brokers: ['url'],
    sasl: {
      mechanism: 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
      username: USERNAME,
      password: PASSWORD
    },
  });
  return kafkaClient;
}

function getKafkaProducerClient() {
      console.log('Trying to fetch kafka producer');

      var producer = getKafkaClient().producer();
      return producer;
}

async function publishToProton(eventToPublish) {

    console.log(`Event before publishing ${JSON.stringify(event)}`); 
    
    var registryClient = getSchemaRegistryClient();

    var encodedMessage = await registryClient.encode(registryId, event);
    let sendParams = {
        topic: topicName,
        messages: [
            {
                key: 'EventKey',
                value: encodedMessage
            }
        ]
    };

    let producer = getKafkaProducerClient();

    await producer.connect();
    await producer.send(sendParams);
    await producer.disconnect();
    console.log(`Proton event is published`);
};

try {
    publishToProton(event);
}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: I am using  @kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry and kafkajs libraries.

Comment: Probably better to refer to the github issue for this. https://github.com/kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry/issues/71